# Coma decimal en el editor de VS

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

Sucede que el separador decimal, de acuerdo a la configuración regional de Windows es la coma, en Excel si presiono del teclado numérico el punto aparece una coma, lo mismo pasa con la calculadora, pero en el editor de código de C#, si coloco punto aparece punto, y al declarar variables esto es correcto.

```
Double num1 = 176.55  //no hay problema
```

Pero si tengo un TextBox y coloco 45.67 y utilizo

```
Double num2 = Convert.ToDouble(TextBox1.Text)
```

Al ejecutar genera error con el punto decimal y en la declaración de num1 no hay tal error, pero no genera error con la coma decimal.
Así que cada vez tengo que estar reemplazando la coma por el punto, y al revés para insertar a la base de datos (ya estoy acostumbrado, pero me aburre).
La pregunta, existe algún lugar en la configuración de VS, que mi separador decimal sea la coma. Quiero que cuando escriba en tiempo de diseño `Double x = 1,45` no me aparezca rojo, porque supuestamente está mal.
Gracias.

Comment: Mira [ask] <- ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] <- ACA para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 1):

Mira esto: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45077006/changing-the-decimal-separator-in-visual-studio-2017

Me parece que VS no tiene una opción para cambiar el separador (lo obtiene de la configuración regional).

Personalmente prefiero definir la cultura a nivel de proyecto.

`System.Globalization.CultureInfo customCulture = (System.Globalization.CultureInfo)System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Clone();
customCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = customCulture;`

Answer (score 0):

Almacena el dato con la coma en un string simpre, cuando lo vayas a operar lo conviertes a double... Y vuelves a guardarlo en un string. Cuando lo guardés en la db cambia la coma por punto. Y solo tienes que hacer un solo cambio, que es cuando lo vuelves a guardar. Porque cuando lo lees de la db y lo almacenas en un string queda con la coma. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Tendrías que definir un objeto Culture.

Primero, agrega el using correspondiente.

```
using System.Globalization;
```

Después declara e inicializa un objeto CultureInfo, después lo pasas como parámetro en la conversión.

```
CultureInfo cultura = new CultureInfo("es-AR");
//Remplazá "es-AR" por tu país.
decimal d = Convert.ToDecimal("TextBox1.Text", cultura);
//Caso decimal
double a = Convert.ToDouble("TextBox1.Text", cultura);
//Caso double
```

Saludos!